# can't convert date into age (The result stil NAN)

Tags: javascript, datepicker

```
 <input type="text" name="tgl_lahir" id="ttl" class="datepicker">
 Usia : &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="usia" id="usia">


<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#ttl" ).datepicker();
});

window.onload=function(){
  $('#ttl').on('change', function() {
        var dob = new Date(this.value);
        var today = new Date();
        var age = Math.floor((today-dob) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 360));
    $('#usia').val(age);
  });
}
</script>
```

Can't convert age in field "usia", if i run the display Nan.. if i select date 21-30 .. but if i select date 1-10 its working  
Maybe the date, can't convert, may you know to convert it ..  
Thank you

Comment: can you check the value of "this.value" & "dob"?

Comment: `window.onload=` *and* a document ready handler?

Comment: Are you trying this in IE? Try `$('#usia').val(age);`. Because `dob` is a date object.

Comment: sorry .. yes i was try $('#usia').val(age); ... and the result is Nan @AshishRajput

Comment: yesss.. its working fine.. its my fault .. i've my answer because the format (Y/m/d) not (d/m/y) .. anyway thankyou

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#usia').val(age);
```

You used wrong value....it should be age
codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ezzXNJ

Comment: sorry .. yes i was try $('#usia').val(age); ... and the result is Nan

Comment: for me it is showing correct age..are you selecting the date birth in the datepicker and trying to find age right?

Comment: oh ..got it....are you using same fields and variables ..my doubt you might be using input type=number instead of text ...

Comment: Try this option to convert age in string to number ,  $('#usia').val(age*1);

Comment: yesss.. its working fine.. its my fault .. i've my answer because the format (Y/m/d) not (d/m/y) .. anyway thankyou

Comment: :) .... Hope it is working as expected...If my answer helped your question.please mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi check this fiddle https://plnkr.co/edit/IpMGFTHez9k2yhL9nnex?p=preview

use

```
onSelect function
```

so it will be easy

JS

```
<script>
  $(function() {

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    <!-- alert("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value); -->
     var dob = new Date(this.value);
        var today = new Date();
        var age = Math.floor((today-dob) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 360));
        console.log(age)
  }
});


  });
  </script>
```

Comment: sorry .. yes i was try $('#usia').val(age); ... and the result is Nan

Comment: check the plunker again i added the input field refresh and check again

Comment: yesss.. its working fine.. its my fault .. i've my answer because the format (Y/m/d) not (d/m/y) .. anyway thankyou

Comment: happy coding @tara